# How to set model attributes named before and after in a FactoryGirl factory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I have a model with attributes before and after.

```
class CreateMyModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :my_model do |t|
      t.text    :before
      t.text    :after
    end
  end
end
```

So when I do this

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :my_model, :class => 'MyModel' do
    before 'some before text'
    after  'some after text'
  end
end
```

it obviously doesn't do what I want, because it sets the callbacks.

Is there a way to set the attributes' values?

UPDATE:

It's not tested yet but I think I've found the solution:

```
factory :my_model, :class => 'MyModel' do |f|
    f.add_attribute :before, 'some before text'
end
```

It's working with :method in another model so I think it must be working here too.

Comment: I realize this isn't the point of your question, but you can omit `:class => 'MyModel'`. FactoryGirl will infer the class name from the factory name.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :my_model, :class => 'MyModel' do |f|
    f.before 'some before text'
    f.after  'some after text'
  end
end
```

Hope I could help.

Comment: sorry for the late reaction. I tried it and didn't work. It seems I've found the solution though (update part of the question).